# NodeJS: Await Skips Catch Block and Exits Function. Why?

Tags: node.js, debugging, async-await, try-catch, node-promisify

this is my first question so give me feedback please.

The file in question is a very large file so I am thinking to use asynchronous reading.

Expected behavior:

Success: "await" will cause the execution of the code to block until the file has been read.

Error: Even if the await fails, any error should be caught by the catch block. The console.log() should indicate that it's being caught.

Observed: The await fails, and the catch block is skipped completely, and execution resumes on the next line of Main. The entire async function is skipped. In the debugger, I can see that the right output in result comes out for just a split second and then it goes straight out of the function.

Can someone please tell me why this is happening and how I can fix it?
It was my understanding that if an exception happens, the catch block will *always* catch it. Please explain in as much detail and clarity as you can, I am still trying to grasp the NodeJS language.

The line that was commented out was another way I thought to do the same task. It also suffers from the same problem. It even skipped a "finally" block when I had one in there too.

Additionally, the "c" variable in Main is a 'pending' promise in the debugger.

Finally, the overall purpose of this code is to parse a JSON file in text form. This is just a MVCE of the bigger file.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');

async function uploadFile(fileName) {
    try {
        const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile);
        result = await readFile(fileName, 'utf-8');
        //result = await fs.readFileSync(fileName, 'utf-8');
        jsonObj = JSON5.parse(result);
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

function Main() {
    fileName = './Diagnostics_Data_Analysis/AddingToDynamoDB/diag.txt';
    var c = uploadFile(fileName);
    console.log("Done");
    process.exit(0);
}

Main();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`await` does not block.  It suspends execution of the local function and that function, then immediately returns a promise.  The caller needs to use that promise to know when the operation is done.  You are actually calling `process.exit()` before your file read has finished.  What is happening here is this:

1. Your code executes `await readFile(fileName, 'utf-8');` and the `uploadFile()` function is suspended and immediately returns a promise.
2. `console.log("Done")` runs
3. `process.exit(0)` runs.
4. The file has not yet been read yet and your program has exited.

Instead, you can do something like this:

```
async function Main() {
    const fileName = './Diagnostics_Data_Analysis/AddingToDynamoDB/diag.txt';
    const c = await uploadFile(fileName);
    console.log("Done");
    process.exit(0);
}
```

This will wait for the `uploadFile()` function to actually notify completion before calling `process.exit(0)`.

P.S. Nodejs now has promise versions of the `fs` library built in already, so you can use `fs.promises.readFile()` and don't have to make your own promisified version of that.